# NameError in Django models.py

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 5 classes, `Customer`, `Supplier`, `Order`, `Design` and `OutSource`.
The `Order` has 3 relationships, one to one with `Customer`, many to many with `Design`and one to one with `OutSourse`. first I just did add it`s one to one relationship with`Customer`(customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer)), now I wanna add the those 2 relationships with`Design`and`Outsourse`.

```
 design=models.ManyToManyField(Design)
 outSource=models.OneToOneField(OutSource)
```

when I do that and run the "makemigrations" command I get this error--> "NameError:name "Design" is not defined"
without those 2 lines of code I can migrate without any kinda problem...can't figure out where I'm going wrong. 
any help will be appreciated.

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    o_type=models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name='Order type')
    number=models.IntegerField()
    date=models.DateField()
    status=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    delivery_date=models.DateField()
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    design=models.ManyToManyField(Design)
    outSource=models.OneToOneField(OutSource)

class Design(models.Model):
    dimension=models.IntegerField()
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')
    number_of_colors=models.IntegerField()
    sides=models.IntegerField(verbose_name='side(s)')

class OutSource(models.Model):
    date=models.DateField()
    number=models.IntegerField()
    description=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code=models.IntegerField()
    supplier=models.ForeignKey(Supplier)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are declaring the class `Design` after actually defining the `ManyToManyField` relationship. It cannot find the class with name `Design` and hence the `NameError`.

Declare the class `Design` before class `Order` and things should work for you.

Comment: Damn you are right! thank you so much @ArpitGoyal :)